# Как применить random.randint к спискам в Python?

Tags: python

```
article = "the", "at", "to", "of"
nouns = "cat", "dog", "girl", "boy"
verb = "sang", "ran", "jumped", "danced"
adverb ="loudly", "quietly", "well", "badly"
```

Есть список ,при помощи функции random.randint() надо вибрать  article ,nouns ,verb ,adverb или article ,nouns , verb.А при помощи random.choice() должно вибирать слово из конкретной строки (т.е. из артиклей: "the" или "at" или "to" и т.д.)

То что примерно должно получится:

```
the boy ran
at girl sang badly
```

Comment: И проблема в чем?

Comment: надо вибрать из article ,nouns ,verb ,adverb или article ,nouns ,verb при помощи random.randint().

Comment: @Dewidson, насколько я понимаю, проблема со времен вашего предыдущего вопроса не изменилась. Если так, то стоило дополнить ваш предыдущий вопрос, а не создавать новый. Тем более, что проблема решается все тем же `random.choice`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, если обязательно randint использовать, то, например, так:

```
from random import choice, randint

article = "the", "at", "to", "of"
nouns = "cat", "dog", "girl", "boy"
verb = "sang", "ran", "jumped", "danced"
adverb = "loudly", "quietly", "well", "badly"

all = article, nouns, verb, adverb
cap = randint(3, 4)
selected = all[:cap]

res = [choice(seq) for seq in selected]
res = ' '.join(res)

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint, choice
l = "one", "two", "three" # любая последовательность
random_element = l[randint(0, len(l)-1]) # 1-й вариант, плохой
random_element = choice(l) # 2-й вариант, хороший
```